# Understanding Server Status for "mem"

Tags: mongodb, memory-mapped-files

Taking a look at the `serverStatus` command, I see the following data.

```
>db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1} )
...

        "mem" : {
                "bits" : 64,
                "resident" : 2138, // Mongo uses 2 GB RAM
                "virtual" : 33272, 
                "supported" : true,
                "mapped" : 16489, // equals db.coll.totalSize()
                "mappedWithJournal" : 32978 
        },
```

Mongo recommends that the [working set size fit in RAM](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#must-my-working-set-size-fit-ram).

If I understand correctly, then 16.4 GB of Mongo documents/indexes are memory mapped. Since Mongo is only using 2 GB of RAM, whenever Mongo needs to access an address outside of that 2 GB, then Mongo will need to fetch the contents of the address on **disk** and then load them into memory?

Is this my explanation the main reason that working set must fit into RAM?

Comment: It doesn't HAVE to but if you expect to not do disk reads, page thrashing and swapping all the time then you need to make sure

Comment: How would I know whether to expect disk reads? For this example, I need to read the `_id`'s of all documents that match my query (which will only use the index). I can't use a covered index since one of the fields in my index is a sub-document.